# Not able to delete document from document library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In SharePoint 2010, I am not able to delete particular file from a document library. while trying to delete the document, its says ACCESS DENIED. I logged into site using SERVICE/SYSTEM ACCOUNT, which has full control. I cannot perform any action on that document.when i try to download the file, its says CANNOT PERFORM THIS ACTION. TO delete the file,I opened the document library using "Open with Explorer" and "Sync with SharePoint Workspace", but I don't find the file which I'm trying to delete. When I opened the site with SharePoint Designer, again I don't find the file. Tried with powershell script also, its not deleting.
How can I delete this file from document library[image]?

Comment: So where do you find that fine?

Comment: I've seen a similar error before, that time it was concurrency errors in the content database causing this issue! Take a look in the Event logs on the SharePoint and SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Items got Orphaned. I got an error in Health Analyzer(Central Admin->Monitoring->Health Analyzer->Review problem and solutions) stating "Content DB has orphaned items". 
On repairing the error(click repair automatically) and re-run. Error resolved and it disappears.
After that, i was able to delete the document.